# Multiply a circulant matrix by a vector with FFT.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fourier-analysis

I am asked to write a Matlab program to find the coefficients of the resulting polynomial which is the product of two other polynomials. However, I need someone to clarify the underlying concepts for me. In this post, I will use $P_a(x)=1+2x+3x^2$ and $P_b=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3$ as our examples for the two polynomials. Using matrix formulation (which is the requirement):
$$
a = \left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
3\\
0\\
0\\
0\end{array} \right)
\qquad b = \left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
0\\
0\\\end{array} \right)
$$
And we are looking for the vector $c$ that is the coefficients of our product polynomial. Since the degree of the resulting polynomial is $5$, we will have $6$ coefficients including the constant term. And I know that $c$ is a product of the circulant matrix of $a$ and the vector $b$:
$$
c = \left(\begin{array}{c}
c_0\\
c_1\\
c_2\\
c_3\\
c_4\\
c_5\end{array} \right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&0&0&0&3&2\\
2&1&0&0&0&3\\
3&2&1&0&0&0\\
0&3&2&1&0&0\\
0&0&3&2&1&0\\
0&0&0&3&2&1\\
\end{array} \right)
\>\dot\
\>\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array} \right)
$$
and we denote the circulant matrix $A$. I know I can construct $A$ by using $FFT$: $$
A = F^{-1}\>diag(F\,a)\>F
$$
And here's what confuses me. From this point on, do I just multiply the matrix A by the vector b **directly**? I am required to implement the algorithm in $O(n\>logn)$ time. And Let me repeat the requirement: **1. Matrix formulation of the problem 2. Using FFT 3. Overall run time being $O(n\>logn)$** Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get $c$ by multiplying the decomposed $A$ by $b$.

Say the decomposed $A$ is , $A=F^{-1} diag(Fa)F$. Then, $c=Ab=F^{-1} diag(Fa)(Fb)$. This says that $c$ can be obtained by taking the IFFT of the vector $diag(Fa)(Fb)$. All you no need to do is, take the FFT of b, FFT a and compute c.