# Circulant matrix-vector product procedure

Tags: matrices, fast-fourier-transform, circulant-matrices

A circulant matrix $C$  can be represented as

$$C = F^{-1} \mbox{diag}(Fc) \, F$$

When $C$ is multiplied by vector $b$

$$C b = F^{-1} \mbox{diag}(Fc) \, (F b)$$

My question only about procedure. As I understood it, to compute $Cb$:

1. Find FFT of $b$.
2. Find FFT of $c$
3. Compute $\mbox{diag}(Fc)*(Fb)$
4. Find IFFT of matrix from the third step.

Am I right?

Comment: This is confusing. What are the inputs and outputs?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo this is process of computing circulant matrix - vector multiplication O(nlogn) . input- circulant matrix and vector , output- vector. whats wrong? sorry for my english :)

Comment: If $F$ is a Fourier matrix, it does not need to be inverted. That is the whole point.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo . b-input vector. c-first row of C

Comment: Why isn't $c$ introduced in your question?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo my question only about the procedure

Comment: What exactly is $F$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo this if fast fourier transfrotm $FFT$

Comment: The FFT is an algorithm used to perform a specific matrix-vector multiplication. I assume that $F$ is a Fourier matrix, but in that case, you do not need to invert it, because it is unitary. Also, please explain how you arrived at the eigenvalues.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes ,FFT there to specific matrix-vector multiplication. i think that i undestood this algorithm incorrect. if you know this algorithm can you help me and say where is my mistake. the picture above i took from this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771568/multiply-a-circulant-matrix-by-a-vector-with-fft?rq=1